# Where do I get a generic driver for a USB flash drive for MS Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, usb-flash-drive

Nope, my Windows XP's "c:[OS folder]\system32\drivers" folder doesn't have it. The technical guys removed it. And nope, automatic driver search doesn't work. Also, the machine doesn't have CD/DVD drive and I don't have the Windows XP CD. Where do I download that driver online?

Comment: Do you have the rights to use USB Flash Drive in the first place? Your technical guys definitely removed them for a reason (e.g. DLP, compliance purposes, etc).

Comment: Go to manufacturer site amd download them.

Comment: @avirk nope, these days manufacturers don't include drivers for very simple things such as USB flash drive. Windows provides it. It's just the technical guys removed it from the drive.

Comment: @fooyoong nope, but i have access to registry editor and did the necessary configuration to enable USB. The only problem is the missing driver. They've removed it from the drive so enabling it won't make it work.

Answer (score 3):

[Run the System File Checker](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833)

Open an [elevated command prompt](http://www.blogsdna.com/2168/windows-7-how-to-open-elevated-command-prompt-with-administrator-privileges.htm) and enter this command

> sfc /scannow

hit the enter key, scan will run and replace any missing or corrupted windows system files and drivers. This should replace the usb drivers that are included in Windows 7.

EDIT: For XP you do not need to open an elevated command prompt, just open cmd and run the same command, it will however ask for your Windows XP install cd.

Comment: This seems very dangerous to run on a coperate machine.

Comment: Safe as it gets....

Comment: I'll try this thing tomorrow but I really doubt this as the driver files have been removed from the drive. And where is this sfc command going to get the files from to replace the missing files in the first place? Most likely it would ask for the Windows CD or something for which I cannot provide. I believe all I need is a download link to driver files for generic USB flash drive. Thanks though.

Comment: Windows stores backup copies or all system files. Vista and W7 no longer ask for the installation dvd, it gets them from the hard drive, and unlike XP it will always have the latest versions.

Comment: @Moab My bad. This is an honest horrible mistake, I thought my machine is on Windows 7 as I usually use Windows 7 but the machine is actually running on Windows XP. I only realized that when it asked me to insert the Windows XP CD. I guess I'll accept this as an answer for Windows 7 and re-post this exact question for Windows XP. See you there. Thanks by the way.

Comment: @supertonsky [SFC](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310747) would probably work in Windows XP too. I do kind of wonder how you mistook XP for 7, though.

Comment: @Bob yes it works for Windows XP but it will require you to insert the disk which I don't have. Yeah, I couldn't believe myself for mistaking Windows XP for 7 LOL.

Comment: @supertonsky no need to ask again, besides its been asked here a lot for XP and your new question will likely be closed, just edit your question and the tags, my answer is goo for XP, Vista and W7.

Comment: @Moab, the SFC command is asking me to provide the disk. The machine doesn't have a CD/DVD drive. It says "Files that are required for Windows to run properly must be copied to the DLL cache. Insert your Windows XP Professional Service Pack 3 CD now.".

Answer (score 1):

download [Driver Identifier](http://www.driveridentifier.com/) and let that tool find out the hardware id of the USB-device you have in your machine .. it will also yield multiple driver-download-urls directly into your face.

[image]

Comment: Let me try this thing tomorrow and see. Thanks akira

Comment: Tried this site, it's giving me broken links to the drivers.

Comment: it lists lots of links, some of them might be broken. what is the device id of the bugging USB-device?

Comment: I tried at least two links and gave up. Device Info: USB Flash Drive 
Hardware ID
 USB\VID_090C&PID_1000&REV_1100
USB\VID_090C&PID_1000 <---- Your Driver


Compatible ID:
USB\CLASS_08&SUBCLASS_06&PROT_50
USB\CLASS_08&SUBCLASS_06
USB\CLASS_08

Comment: so it's a cardreader? that link here worked http://www.driveridentifier.com/scan/download_file.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fglobal-download.acer.com%2FGDFiles%2FDriver%2FCardReader%2FCardReader_Realtek_6.0.6000.20113_Vistax64Vistax86_A.zip%3Facerid%3D633833924736249602%26Step1%3DNotebook%26Step2%3DAspire%26Step3%3DAspire+4732Z%26OS%3DV01%26LC%3Den%26BC%3DAcer%26SC%3DPA_7++&hardware_id=USB%5CVID_090C%26PID_1000&driver_inf_file_id=89165&scanid=ACAB05D6FFC54175887193CA29C7F03B

Comment: i think we're making progress here. I have downloaded the file and installed it. The USB flash is now showing with an exclamation mark icon. Clicking on update driver button allows me to locate the driver manually. I'm now getting "The file RTSTOR.sys on Realtek Vista Multi-LUN USB Mass Storage Driver is needed." I specified the location of that file but it did not seem not to accept it. I just re-displays the same dialog box.

Comment: Ok some how I managed to install it by choosing an alternative way. It is now showing as "Realtek Card Reader" on my device manager. Apparently I can't see any additional storage on my windows explorer. I tried looking at "Computer management -> Disk Management" and I can't see my USB flash drive. It seems like it is literally treating it as a card reader and not as a flash drive.

Comment: @supertonsky: as long as you can read/write data to the device and the data you write is the same as the date you can read .. all fine.

Comment: I can't read/write data to the device. It's not even showing on my Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than a dozen generic USBxxxx.sys drivers in that folder (hidden) C:\Windows\SysWOW64\drivers\usbscan.sys also
Evidence of drivers will be shown in Device Manager under USB at the bottom.
How many Hubs do you see? That will tell you if the drivers are enabled.

Comment: This is all I got on that folder: usb8023.sys
usbcamd.sys
usbcamd2.sys
usbccgp.sys
usbccid.sys
usbd.sys
usbehci.sys
usbhub.sys
usbintel.sys
usbport.sys
usbstor.sys

Comment: There are two USB hubs and two USB Root Hubs currently showing up but the USB Flash Drive is showing as a question mark icon as any device without drivers would.